# Adapt a function to work when windows are split only vertically

Tags: window-splitting

As @drew asked me to do [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62787/activate-a-mode-when-only-one-window-is-displayed?noredirect=1#comment98960_62787) I'm asking one question per problem

I'm trying to enable/disable visual-fill-column when there is one window/multiple windows.

```el
(defun my-visual-fill-one-window ()
  (global-visual-fill-column-mode -1)
  (if (one-window-p)
    (global-visual-fill-column-mode 1)
    (global-visual-fill-column-mode -1)))
    
(add-hook 'window-state-change-hook 'my-visual-fill-one-window)
```

Could it be possible to adapt this function to work not when there's only one window but when they are just split vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `one-window-p` with `window-full-width-p`.

> **Function: window-full-width-p *&optional window***
>
> This function returns non-nil if *window* has no other window to the left or right in its frame, i.e., its total width equals that of the
> root window on that frame. If *window* is omitted or nil, it defaults to
> the selected window.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Sizes.html.